# Haskell: Pattern matching, Identifiers and operators

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, type-signature

I'm trying to define `xor` using pattern matching in Haskell by:

```
(xor) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
True    xor False   = True
False   xor True    = True
True    xor True    = False
False   xor False   = False
```

However this gives the error:

```
Invalid type signature: (xor) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
Should be of form <variable> :: <type>
```

I'm confused as to why this error is being thrown. Also if I replace `xor` with something such as `&&` the script loads fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Haskell differentiates between *identifiers* and *operator symbols*.  Identifiers are alphanumeric plus `'`, and are valid terms on their own; if an identifier `prefix` has a function type, you can thus call it as `prefix arg1 arg2`.  Operator names are sequences of symbols, and are called as `arg1 !&$ arg2`.<sup>1</sup>  But sometimes, you want to use identifiers as infix operators or treat an infix operator as an identifier.  Thus, if you surround any prefix function name with `` ` ``s, it becomes an operator and you can (must) use it as infix: `` arg1 `prefixFunc` arg2 ``.  And contrariwise, if you wrap an infix operator name in parentheses, it becomes syntactically valid on its own, and so can be called in prefix form: `(!&$) arg1 arg2`.<sup>2</sup>

When declaring a type signature for a variable, you need to give the variable's name *as an identifier*.<sup>3</sup>  For an ordinary function name like `xor`, that's just the name; for an operator like `&&`, you wrap it in parentheses, as discussed above, which is why you write `(&&) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool`.  Thus, you'd write

```
xor :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
True  `xor` False = True
False `xor` True  = True
True  `xor` True  = False
False `xor` False = False
```

Note that I had to make two changes.  If you left off the backticks in the definition lines, it'll be as though you were trying to do pattern matching: `True` would look like a constructor which took two arguments, and `xor` would be the first one.<sup>4</sup>

(Also, just for kicks, a shorter definition: `xor = (/=)` :-))

---

#### Citations in [the Haskell 2010 report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/):

<sup>1</sup> The lexical structure is in [§2.4](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-180002.4)

<sup>2</sup> The expression structure is in [§3.2](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-240003.2).

<sup>3</sup> The structure of type signatures is in [§4.4.1](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-810004.4.1), referring to the definition of *var* in [§3.2](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-240003.2).

<sup>4</sup> The structure of bindings is in [§4.4.3](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-830004.4.3).

Answer (score 15):

Only operators should be enclosed in parentheses for the type signature, like

```
(&&) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
```

ordinary functions shall be written without,

```
xor :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
```

and in the defining equations, you must enclose it in backticks,

```
True `xor` True = False
```

if you want to define it using infix notation. Without backticks, you can define it using prefix notation,

```
xor True False = True
```

Note, however,

- `xor` is a function from the `Bits` class, so using it for `Bool` may be unexpected
- `xor ≡ (/=)`